# How to reuse existing HTML element in a modal?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-4

Consider a UI that has a custom component `<foo>`- for now assume its just text.

```
<foo id="foo-id">SOMETEXT</foo>
```

I'd like to display this content in two places on the UI - one of which is in a modal.  How can I have the modal content delegate to this existing element?  I'm using open to Jquery/angularjs or native HTML solutions.

```
<foo id="foo-id">SOMETEXT</foo>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" ...>
      ...
      <div class="modal-body">
        ### REFERENCE TO ID #foo-id here ###
      </div>
  </div
```

I'm trying to avoid using a second instance of the element, eg:

```
<foo id="foo-id">SOMETEXT</foo>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" ...>
      ...
      <div class="modal-body">
            <foo id="foo-id-2">SOMETEXT</foo>
      </div>
  </div
```

### More Context

The reason I actually want to do this is because we have a webpage with a dropdown expander that already renders rich components.  We're trying to add a "popout" button that would display the rendered element in a modal window.  Because the elements are already in the correct loaded state at the time of popout being pressed, then it makes sense to just delegate the component to a pre-defined one rather than recreating.

**Stack** is angularJS, bootstrap 3, jquery and I cannot change this :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you not need have two copy you could try detach the element and insert it at his new place

```
let $fooContent = $("#foo-id");
let $myModal = $("#exampleModal > .modal-body");
...

// set it
$myModal.html( $fooContent.detach() );

// back it
$initialFooContentLocation.append( $fooContent.detach() );
```

Comment: So I thought this was the solution but when I did this, all of the HTML elements that are shown in the modal don't work.  For example, if the element had buttons and other dynamic content, they no longer work when rendered in the modal.  Is this expected?

Comment: does you events are set with .on/.live onto the original wrapper ? it must work fine if set directly with elements, but yet i don't know how angular would work in case like this

Comment: I don't have any explicit bindings like that

Comment: does it work again when you back it in original place ?
to test event following the dom part you may also try put a direct event $fooContent.on('click', 'button', alert.bind(null,"work")); if it work it may be an angular specific issue or how you declare your jquery events

Comment: Nevermind - there was some typo in my implementation or something.  I ended up having to select the modal body directly by an ID than the way you were doing here and it seems to work.  So probably the selector in my app was targeted more than one modal.  

Thanks again - let me mark this as accepted

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it in vanilla javascript is creating a function that creates a modal element and then append it to the DOM element you want e.g. the body.

An example:

```
function createModal(modalId, fooElement){
  const modalDiv = document.createElement('div');
  modalDiv.classList.add('modal');
  modalDiv.classList.add('fade');
  modalDiv.id = modalId;

  const modalBodyDiv = document.createElement('div');
  modalBodyDiv.classList.add('modal-body');

  modalBodyDiv.append(fooElement);

  return modalDiv;
}
```

And then use it to create N modal elements and append them wherever you want e.g. the body, like this:

```
const modal1 = createModal('myModal1', fooElement);

document.body.append(modal1)
```

This way your html will be cleaner.
Note: this `fooElement` must be a DOM element, otherwise it will throw an error.
Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer worked for me; however, for completeness here's another approach.

Use `$scope/$rootScope` event emitters to broadcast events between components.  If the components have a clear parent/child relationship, `$scope` is usually adequate and if they are siblings, then they can share events via `$rootScope`.

Since this is an angularJS project, I followed [this simple guide.](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/5d8be0b6-e294-457e-82b0-ba7cc10cae0e.aspx)